# How does R/C compute the binomial distribution?

Tags: c++, r

In `R` the cumulative distribution function for the binomial distribution is called via an underlying C/C++ function called `C_pbinom`.    I am trying to find the underlying code for this algorithm, so that I can find out what algorithm this function uses to compute the cumulative distribution function.  Unfortunately, I have not been successful in finding the underlying code, nor any information on the algorithm that is used.

**My question:** How do I find the underlying C/C++ code for the function `C_pbinom`.   Alternatively, is there any information source available showing the algorithm used by this function?

---

**What I have done so far:** Calling `pbinom` in `R` gives the following details:

```
function (q, size, prob, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE) 
.Call(C_pbinom, q, size, prob, lower.tail, log.p)
<bytecode: 0x000000000948c5a0>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

I have located and opened the underlying `NAMESPACE` file in the `stats` library.  This file lists various functions, including the `pbinom` function, but does not give code for the `C_pbinom` function, nor any pointer to where it can be found.  I have also read a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) on finding source code in `R`, and an article [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf) on "compiling source codes", but neither has been of sufficient assistance to let me find the code.  At this point I have his a dead end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I went to the Github mirror for the R source code, [searched for `pbinom`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?l=C&q=pbinom), and filtered to C: that got me [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/pbinom.c). The meat of the function is simply

```
pbeta(p, x + 1, n - x, !lower_tail, log_p)
```

This is invoking the incomplete beta function (= CDF of the Beta distribution): it means you need to in turn [look up the `pbeta` function in the code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/search?l=C&q=pbinom): [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/pbeta.c), it says that the code is "a wrapper for TOMS708" , which is in  [src/nmath/toms708.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/nmath/toms708.c) and described in a little more detail [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/f77_src/toms708/toms708.html) (google "TOMS 708") ... original code [here](http://www.netlib.org/toms/index.html).

The full reference is [here](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=131776):    Didonato and Morris, Jr.,
ACM Transactions on Mathematical Software (TOMS), Volume 18 Issue 3, Sept. 1992, Pages 360-373.